# Can you mount a React class programmatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mvvm

I am trying to implement the mvvm pattern with React.I am currently doing this by building a "dumb" component (the view) that depends on a "viewModel" function. The function returns all the relevant state and business logic (like event handlers etc.).

I am wondering if I can use this same method but with a react Class instead of a React function. I have added a simple counter example trying to implement this idea. I have access to the state but when I click on the increase count button I get an error: Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.

https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-sound-ogerg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to force a design pattern on react it wasn't built for?

Comment: @Krismu. Correct me if I am wrong but to my knowledge React is un-opinionated about design patterns.

Comment: That's not quite true. There are definitely things that are considered anti pattern, for instance your imperative approach instead of keeping things declarative. React on the same time tries to stay accessible to a wide range of programmers, so you can definitely make your approach work, e.g. by using class attribute instead of state. You can read this article on react design principles from their official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/design-principles.html